# How to edit the image expansion screen of image_picker package in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image-picker

I want to edit the image expansion screen like Zalo [image expansion screen of Zalo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS8c2.jpg) (I use image_picker package) but I don't find out the code for that screen in image_picker lib. I want to find out that in order to add my edit tools.
[Default image expansion screen of image_picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxb4c.jpg)